# For a non-abelian group, there exists an non-trivial element whose normalizer is abelian subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

"If $G$ is a finite non-abelian group, then there exists an element $a\in G$ whose normalizer is abelian. Here $N(a)= \{g \in G : ga=ag \}$ is normalizer of a."

I have verified the above fact for the symmetric group $S_{3}$. I was trying it for quite long, but couldn't get anything. Any help or hint would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this holds for finite simple groups though.

Comment: @MoisheCohen That does seem like it might be the case. I have had GAP running all day trying to find an example of a simple group where it fails, but so far it has not found any.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft This guess is motivated by simple complex Lie groups where it is true (one takes any regular semisimple element).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim is not true. There is a counterexample of order $32$ which is a semidirect product of $D_8\times C_2$ with $C_2$. I found this example by asking GAP to go through the groups and check. The group in question is the one with ID [32,49].

Note that what you have written up is the definition of the centralizer of that element, not the normalizer. Normalizers are usually defined for subgroups, but one can also define them for elements as the normalizer of the subgroup generated by them.

Comment: Why does minimality imply that every proper subgroup of $G$ is abelian? On the face of it, minimality only implies that for every proper subgroup $H< G$ the centralizer $Z_H(a)$ of every $a\in H$ is abelian.

Comment: @MoisheCohen You are right, I need to think about this some more. If I can't fix it shortly, I will delete the answer for now.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Ok, I have now fixed it and undeleted. It turned out that the claim was not true after all.

Comment: How does $C_2$ act on the product? Is it by an inner automorphism of $D_8$ and trivially on the $C_2$ factor?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I did not actually check (I don't recall how to figure this out in a nice way). It is the group with ID [32,49] (I will add this to the answer as well).

Comment: Sorry, but I am not buying this example. I do not know what ID[32,49] is, but given your description, the only reasonable thing to do for the automorphism is to fix $C_2$ and swap the two generators $s_1, s_2$ of $D_8$. But then $s_1$ will have abelian centralizer in the resulting group.

Comment: @MoisheCohen There are plenty of other things it could do (the automorphism group of $D_8\times C_2$ has $9$ conjugacy classes of subgroups of order $2$ to choose from). I checked all the centralizer in GAP, and they are all non-abelian. I don't have time to work out the precise action right now, but it certainly mixes the two factors in the direct product, so while (as far as I could tell) it does fix the generator $g$ of $C_2$, it sends some of the elements of the form $(x,e)$ to ones of the form $(y,g)$, or even to $(x,g)$.

Comment: yes, and `SmallGroup(32,50)` is the other of the 2 groups of order 32 with such property. Furthermore, there are 7 of such groups of order 64, and 29 - of order 128.

Comment: Here is the action, according to GAP: let the generator of the $C_2$ factor be $x$, and the generators of $D_8$ factor be $y$ and $z$, with $(yz)^4=1$. Then $K=\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is a normal subgroup, and we have an element $a$ such that $\langle a,K\rangle=G$, with $a^2=1$.  Note that $c=(yz)^2$ is central.  The action by $a$ is given by: $x^a=xc$; $y^a=yc$; $z^a=z$.